# How to get the right order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have written queries to get the total qty of each month in 2016. Then I added another row called *Total* to sum up the total qty in 2016. But the *ordermonth* in the result turned out to be in a mess.

So, the question is is there any way to put the *ordermonth* in the right order? Both `ASC` and `DESC` are OK. Thanks in advance.

The query I've written:

```
WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), MONTH(orderdate)) AS ordermonth, SUM(qty) AS qty
        FROM dbo.orders
        WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2016
        GROUP BY MONTH(orderdate)
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE 

UNION

SELECT 'Total', SUM(qty)
FROM dbo.orders
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2016;
```

Current result:

```
ordermonth  qty
1           4134
10          6454
11          9780
12          4000
2           5548
3           6970
4           3543
5           3309
6           4251
7           4997
8           6134
9           6926
Total      66046
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links.)

Comment: @jarlhSorry about that. I have no right to show the image directly since I'm new to SO. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Formatted text is even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put into subquery and try like below:

```
select * from (
 --your query including cte and union 
  ) a
  order by case when a.[Month] = 'Total' then 9999 else convert(int,a.[Month]) end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can do what you want without `UNION`.  Something like this:

```
select coalesce(cast(month(orderdate) as varchar(255)), 'Total') as mon . . .
from . . .
group by grouping sets (month(orderdate), ())
order by month(orderdate)
```

No CTE, that's the entire query.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort it by yyyymm, that is the best way even when you'll have more than one year, i.e.

```
order by orderyear * 100 + ordermonth
```

Or you can just add '0' for getting the right order like this:

```
order by right('0' + cast(ordermonth as varchar(2)), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to solve this issue, that is, replacing UNION with UNION ALL.

```
WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), MONTH(orderdate)) AS ordermonth, SUM(qty) AS qty
        FROM dbo.orders
        WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2016
        GROUP BY MONTH(orderdate)
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE 

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', SUM(qty)
FROM dbo.orders
WHERE YEAR(orderdate) = 2016;
```